# Vertically center tikzpicture in table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'm tryin to vertically center a `tikzpicture` in a table. Here's a not-very-minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver og andet godt fra havet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} % noget matematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % mere matematik
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % andre margener og andet gøgl
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Type} & \textbf{Hvilke} & \textbf{Tegning} & \textbf{CFSE} \\
\midrule
Plankvadratisk & Generelt i 5. og 6. periode og nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (2,3) -- (5,3);
\draw (2,4.5) -- (5,4.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\\
\\

Tetraedrisk & Generelt i 4. periode på nær nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);
\draw (-2,1.5) -- (1,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{3}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{2}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{tet}}$ \\\\
Octaedrisk & Har 6 bindinger til ligander & 
%\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{oct.png} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);
\draw (8,0) -- (11,0);
\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{2}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{3}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{oct}}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

[image]

I'd like to vertically center these tikzpictures in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to auto-center the `tikz` images, it is simpler to just apply a `\raisebox` to each `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver og andet godt fra havet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} % noget matematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % mere matematik
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % andre margener og andet gøgl
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Type} & \textbf{Hvilke} & \textbf{Tegning} & \textbf{CFSE} \\
\midrule
Plankvadratisk & Generelt i 5. og 6. periode og nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\raisebox{-30pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (2,3) -- (5,3);
\draw (2,4.5) -- (5,4.5);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\\
\\

Tetraedrisk & Generelt i 4. periode på nær nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\raisebox{-15pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);
\draw (-2,1.5) -- (1,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{3}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{2}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{tet}}$ \\\\
Octaedrisk & Har 6 bindinger til ligander & 
%\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{oct.png} 

\raisebox{-10pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);
\draw (8,0) -- (11,0);
\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{2}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{3}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{oct}}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a Tikz based solution, you can use the `baseline` option to align the pictures to their north anchor in a somewhat automatic way. I've marked the new code with "new code":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver og andet godt fra havet
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} % noget matematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % mere matematik
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % andre margener og andet gøgl
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Type} & \textbf{Hvilke} & \textbf{Tegning} & \textbf{CFSE} \\
\midrule
Plankvadratisk & Generelt i 5. og 6. periode og nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt,baseline=(current bounding box.north)]  %new code
]

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (2,3) -- (5,3);
\draw (2,4.5) -- (5,4.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\\
\\

Tetraedrisk & Generelt i 4. periode på nær nikkel. Har 4 bindinger til ligander & 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, line width=1pt,baseline=(current bounding box.north)] %new code

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);

\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);
\draw (-2,1.5) -- (1,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{3}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{2}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{tet}}$ \\\\
Octaedrisk & Har 6 bindinger til ligander & 
%\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{oct.png} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, baseline=(current bounding box.north)] %new code

\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (7,0);
\draw (8,0) -- (11,0);
\draw (2,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw (6,1.5) -- (9,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

& CFSE $= \left(-\frac{2}{5} \cdot e^- + \frac{3}{5} \cdot e^-\right)\Delta_{\text{oct}}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are unhappy with the "automatic" vertical alignment (for example in the second row) you can still specify a custom baseline value, like `baseline=15pt` or whatever you like.

[image]