# Vertically center elements in rows of array

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, diagrams, arrays

In the following table, I would like to center the Venn diagrams vertically. Here is a MWE showing my diagrams aligned "top":

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,american]{article}
\usepackage[left=1 in, right=1 in, top=1 in, bottom=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,hyperref,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

%Command for creating Venn diagrams (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266326/generate-all-16-possible-2-variable-shaded-venn-diagrams-in-tikz):
\makeatletter
\def\venn@strip#1#2\venn@STOP{\def\venn@next{#1}\gdef\venn@rest{#2}}
\newcommand{\venn}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15]
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (5,-3);
\coordinate (W) at (-3,{sqrt(3)+1.5});
\edef\venn@rest{#10000}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\expandafter\venn@strip\venn@rest\venn@STOP
\ifnum\venn@next=1\relax
\pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (A) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/2),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (B) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/4),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\fill[gray] (E) rectangle (W);
\fi
\end{scope}
}
\draw[thick] (A) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (B) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (E) rectangle (W);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Truth Table} & \textrm{Venn Diagram} & \textrm{Connective} & \textrm{Connective Name} \\
\hline
FFFF & \venn{0000} & \mathscr{P} \perp \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Contradiction} \\
FFFT & \venn{0001} & \mathscr{P} \overline{\lor} \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Nondisjunction (Nor)} \\
FFTF & \venn{0010} & \mathscr{P} \centernot\impliedby \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Converse Nonimplication} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

I tried the `raisebox` method suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219665/vertically-center-tikzpicture-in-table), and here is the MWE for that:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,american]{article}
\usepackage[left=1 in, right=1 in, top=1 in, bottom=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,hyperref,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

%Command for creating Venn diagrams (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266326/generate-all-16-possible-2-variable-shaded-venn-diagrams-in-tikz):
\makeatletter
\def\venn@strip#1#2\venn@STOP{\def\venn@next{#1}\gdef\venn@rest{#2}}
\newcommand{\venn}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15]
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (5,-3);
\coordinate (W) at (-3,{sqrt(3)+1.5});
\edef\venn@rest{#10000}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\expandafter\venn@strip\venn@rest\venn@STOP
\ifnum\venn@next=1\relax
\pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (A) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/2),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (B) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/4),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\fill[gray] (E) rectangle (W);
\fi
\end{scope}
}
\draw[thick] (A) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (B) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (E) rectangle (W);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Truth Table} & \textrm{Venn Diagram} & \textrm{Connective} & \textrm{Connective Name} \\
\hline
FFFF & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0000} } & \mathscr{P} \perp \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Contradiction} \\
FFFT & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0001} } & \mathscr{P} \overline{\lor} \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Nondisjunction (Nor)} \\
FFTF & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0010} } & \mathscr{P} \centernot\impliedby \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Converse Nonimplication} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

however, this seems to cause my diagrams to slide to the left, losing horizontal alignment! Hence I am looking for an alternative approach that can improve how this is turning out visually.

By the way, I am by no means committed to `array`, so if you have a different suggestion (like using `tabular` or `tabularx` or something else), I am definitely open to your ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `baseline` option to `tikzpicture`

```
\newcommand{\venn}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15,baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
```

This will give

[image]

In your approach using `\raisebox`, you have an extra space before the closing brace:

```
\raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0010} }
```

which should be

```
\raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0010}}  %<-- no space here before }
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,american]{article}
\usepackage[left=1 in, right=1 in, top=1 in, bottom=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,hyperref,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

%Command for creating Venn diagrams (from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266326/generate-all-16-possible-2-variable-shaded-venn-diagrams-in-tikz):
\makeatletter
\def\venn@strip#1#2\venn@STOP{\def\venn@next{#1}\gdef\venn@rest{#2}}
\newcommand{\venn}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15]
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (5,-3);
\coordinate (W) at (-3,{sqrt(3)+1.5});
\edef\venn@rest{#10000}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\expandafter\venn@strip\venn@rest\venn@STOP
\ifnum\venn@next=1\relax
\pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (A) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/2),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\path[clip] \pgfmathresult (B) circle[radius=2];
\pgfmathparse{Mod(floor(\i/4),2) == 1 ? "(E) rectangle (W)" : ""}
\fill[gray] (E) rectangle (W);
\fi
\end{scope}
}
\draw[thick] (A) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (B) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick] (E) rectangle (W);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Truth Table} & \textrm{Venn Diagram} & \textrm{Connective} & \textrm{Connective Name} \\
\hline
FFFF & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0000}} & \mathscr{P} \perp \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Contradiction} \\
FFFT & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0001}} & \mathscr{P} \overline{\lor} \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Nondisjunction (Nor)} \\
FFTF & \raisebox{-.35\height}{\venn{0010}} & \mathscr{P} \centernot\impliedby \mathscr{Q} & \textrm{Converse Nonimplication} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]